# Can't assign a CRS to Sentinel-3 OLCI NetCDF using Terra R package

Tags: r, geospatial, netcdf, projection, terra

For context, this is a Sentinel-3 OLCI product that is an output from ACOLITE. The final output of this process is a NetCDF file, which has no CRS information.

I have tried to define a template raster in R using identical dimensions. I was also able to export the same image as a GeoTiff from ArcGIS and add a CRS in R. However, regardless of method, I get the following error.
Error: [project] input raster CRS not set.

```
s3 = rast("..../S3A_OLCI_2022_07_14_15_37_07_L2R.nc")
crs (s3)
# [1] ""
dim(s3)
# [1] 4091 4865   43
s3_tmp = rast(".../S3A_OLCI_2022_07_14_15_37.tif")
# projected dim result is more x and y pixels to keep rectangle
dim(s3_tmp)
# [1] 5939 2676    1

crs(s3_tmp)
#[1] "GEOGCRS[\"WGS 84\",\n    ENSEMBLE[\"World Geodetic System 1984 ensemble\",\n        MEMBER[\"World Geodetic System 1984 (Transit)\"],\n        MEMBER[\"World Geodetic System 1984 (G730)\"],\n        MEMBER[\"World Geodetic System 1984 (G873)\"],\n        MEMBER[\"World Geodetic System 1984 (G1150)\"],\n        MEMBER[\"World Geodetic System 1984 (G1674)\"],\n        MEMBER[\"World Geodetic System 1984 (G1762)\"],\n        MEMBER[\"World Geodetic System 1984 (G2139)\"],\n        ELLIPSOID[\"WGS 84\",6378137,298.257223563,\n            LENGTHUNIT[\"metre\",1]],\n        ENSEMBLEACCURACY[2.0]],\n    PRIMEM[\"Greenwich\",0,\n        ANGLEUNIT[\"degree\",0.0174532925199433]],\n    CS[ellipsoidal,2],\n        AXIS[\"geodetic latitude (Lat)\",north,\n            ORDER[1],\n            ANGLEUNIT[\"degree\",0.0174532925199433]],\n        AXIS[\"geodetic longitude (Lon)\",east,\n            ORDER[2],\n            ANGLEUNIT[\"degree\",0.0174532925199433]],\n    USAGE[\n        SCOPE[\"Horizontal component of 3D system.\"],\n        AREA[\"World.\"],\n        BBOX[-90,-180,90,180]],\n    ID[\"EPSG\",4326]]"

s3_proj <- terra::project(s3,s3_tmp)

Error: [project] input raster CRS not set.
```

Simply want to project a NetCDF that has no CRS information in its native format.